# Github-Pages with Quarto giving 404 but website renders fine in rstudio

Tags: r, github-pages, quarto

I'm trying to use quarto to build a github pages site. Note that this is in an enterprise github, not public.

I'm developing the site in RStudio and I can preview render it just fine. I'm doing development in the `main` branch.

```
(base) balter@exahead1:~/chse.github.io$ quarto publish gh-pages
? Update site at git@source.ohsu.edu:chse/chse.github.io.git? (Y/n) › Yes
From source.ohsu.edu:chse/chse.github.io
 * branch            gh-pages   -> FETCH_HEAD
Rendering for publish:
.....
.....
.....
branch 'gh-pages' set up to track 'origin/gh-pages'.
HEAD is now at 907ad21 Built site for gh-pages
Preparing worktree (resetting branch 'gh-pages'; was at 907ad21)
Updating files: 100% (119/119), done.
[gh-pages a6042cf] Built site for gh-pages
 3 files changed, 7 insertions(+), 7 deletions(-)
origin  git@source.ohsu.edu:chse/chse.github.io.git (fetch)
origin  git@source.ohsu.edu:chse/chse.github.io.git (push)
To source.ohsu.edu:chse/chse.github.io.git
   907ad21..a6042cf  HEAD -> gh-pages
```

I get no errors during processing, however, the site gives me a 404 error.

Note: I did originally test it with a vanilla .html file to make sure I could visit a site at the URL.